# Restrict Submission on Cognito Forms' Form Based on Previous Entries

Tags: forms, lookup

I built a form in Cognito Forms for employees to reserve company vehicles. The following are important fields on the form:

- **Employee Name**
- **Employee Email**
- **Vehicle** (selection)
- **Pick Up Date** = date the user will get the car
- **Mileage** = how many miles the user put on the car, entered after returning the car

We want to restrict the user from entering a new car reservation if they have a past entry that has ***not*** had Mileage entered. I was considering using a calculated field of some kind and then using the quantities feature to restrict duplicate entries but not sure what could be used in the form as comparison for duplicates. I know that currently Cognito Forms does not have a method for doing lookups of previous entries or else there wouldn't be a question. Has anyone else found a workaround before?

Comment: I found a workaround for now, so there's one solution in a way. What I did was add a couple calculated fields that check against Pick Up Date, and if it's in the past labels it PAST, and connects that to the email.

Comment: Then I made one of these calculated fields a limited quantity field (of like 10,000 entries). Then I created a calculated yes/no field called Permission and used one of the 3 new quantity values (_QuantityUsed) to say if there have been any past usages of the calculated field including PAST before, set it to NO and if there haven't been, set it to YES. Then I made all the fields of the form hidden if Permission is NO except for a content field containing the message along the lines of, "You need to enter mileage for one of your past reservations." Tested and it works.

Comment: This did not work, actually. The logic was not consistent because it only looked at the current entry and any calculation resulted in quantity being used. Does anyone know of something else I could do?